# PHP : ReflectionParameter, isOptional vs isDefaultValueAvailable

Tags: php, reflection

What is the difference between two. both of these are working exactly in a same way.

```
public static function getArgsArray($reflectionMethod,$argArray){
    $arr = array();
    foreach($reflectionMethod->getParameters() as $key => $val){
        $arr[$val->getName()] = isset($argArray[$val->getName()]) ?
        $argArray[$val->getName()] : (isset($_REQUEST[$val->getName()])
                ? $_REQUEST[$val->getName()] : ($val->*isDefaultValueAvailable()*  ? $val->getDefaultValue() : NULL));
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: Be very careful with those nested ternary statements. Nothing but trouble IMHO

Comment: You have any example it fails? ternary statements?

Comment: They're just hard to read and the logic process is not always clear. See the note here ~ http://php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php#example-137

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good question. Consider this example

```
function foo($foo = 'foo', $bar) {}
```

For the `$foo` parameter, `isDefaultValueAvailable()` would understandably return `true` however `isOptional()` would return `false` as the next parameter (`$bar`) has no default value and is therefore not optional. To support the non-optional `$bar` parameter, `$foo` must itself be non-optional.

Hope this makes sense ;)

I've noted that behaviour differs across PHP versions. 5.5 returns the above whereas 5.4 says parameter 1 is both not optional and has no default value.

- PHP 5.4 - https://eval.in/154641
- PHP 5.5 - https://eval.in/154642

Comment: You mean, in your example, $foo='foo' will make sense if i call it like this foo(null,'hello') but not foo('helllo')

Comment: @LNT Well, that would just set `$foo` to `null`. It's a silly way to write a function but not impossible, therefore the reflection utils need to differentiate

Answer (score 7):

The function `isDefaultValueAvailable` can work only on user defined function, and not work on system functions (PHP core).

So, as example:

```
class Foo
{
    public function foo($var = null)
    {
    }
}

// Get the "var" argument in method Foo::foo
$refParameter = (new ReflectionClass('Foo'))->getMethod('foo')->getParameters()[0];

print "User function Foo::foo:\n\n";

print 'Optional: ' . ($refParameter->isOptional() ? 'true' : 'false') . "\n";
print 'Default available: ' . ($refParameter->isDefaultValueAvailable() ? 'true' : 'false') . "\n";
if ($refParameter->isDefaultValueAvailable()) {
    print 'Default value: ' . var_export($refParameter->getDefaultValue(), 1);
}

print "\n\n";

print "System function substr\n\n";

// Get the "length" parameter from function substr
$refParameter = (new \ReflectionFunction('substr'))->getParameters()[2];

print 'Optional: ' . ($refParameter->isOptional() ? 'true' : 'false') . "\n";
print 'Default available: ' . ($refParameter->isDefaultValueAvailable() ? 'true' : 'false') . "\n";
if ($refParameter->isDefaultValueAvailable()) {
    print 'Default value: ' . var_export($refParameter->getDefaultValue(), 1);
}

print "\n\n";
```

And, this code shows: your can get default value only from user defined function and can not get from system function (`substr` as example). But the method `isOptional` returned `true` in user defined function and system function.

Conclusion:

- If your want check the parameter is optional, your must use `isOptional`  method.
- You can get the default value only from the user defined function.
- You can not use method `isDefaultValueAvailable` on system (PHP) defined function.

Source: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ccf863c8ce7e746948fb060d515960492c41ed27/ext/reflection/php_reflection.c#L2536-L2573

Comment: Thanks, got your point, I m only using it for user defined fucntions